# How to update Primefaces component in one page from command button in another page when both pages are included in one page

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have 2 pages

`input.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="Name : "/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{inputBean.name}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="2" >
                <p:commandButton action="#{inputBean.buttonAction}" value="Submit"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

`display.xhtml`

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:outputText value="#{inputBean.name}" id="dis123"/>
</h:form>
```

If I include both of them in a single page like below

`index.xhtml`

```
<p:accordionPanel widgetVar="main" multiple="true">
    <p:tab title="Input">
        <ui:include src="input.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab title="Output">
        <ui:include src="display.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

can I call `update="dis123"` from command button in `input.xhtml`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you can't. A relative client ID like `update="dis123"` basically searches in the same `NamingContainer` parent component which is in your case the `<h:form>` of the first page. However, no such component exist. It's actually in a different `NamingContainer` parent. You need to provide an absolute client ID instead: `update=":form1:dis123"`.

For starters, an easy way to figure the right absolute client ID is by just looking in the JSF-generated HTML output (rightclick, *View Source* in browser) for the generated HTML element ID of the desired component and then prefix it with `:`.

Please note that this all has nothing to do with includes. You'd have had exactly the same problem when having all the code in a single page.

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)