# Ajax update=":#{table.clientId}" does not seem to work on <p:dataTable>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have some problems with PrimeFaces 5.2 and client components update mechanism

I created a web page with a button that triggers a server side method. This method update a List of objects and finally
a datatable will be updated with new contents of the List.

```
<h:form> 
        ...
        <p:commandButton value="Add parameters" action="#{adminBean.addParams}"  
                         update=":growl :#{tblSensors.clientId}"  />
</h:form>

<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="tblSensors"  
            var="sensorElem" value="#{adminBean.sensors}"
            binding="#{tblSensors}"
        >  
            ...
        </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Unfortunatelly when the procedure callback is over, my data table are not updated .. Sincerlly I'm not able to find the problem.

There are no exception in debug phase and I saw nothing in Response data from Firebug.

**UPDATE:** I saw that when the bean method is called and some variable has been changed; this changes aren't persistent and they are missed every time the method is called

**UPDATE 2:** as requested, I add the bean code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="adminBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AdminBean implements Serializable{
    private List<Sensor> sensors;


    public List<Sensor> getSensors() {
        return sensors;
    }

    public void setSensors(List<Sensor> sensors) {
        this.sensors = sensors;
    }


    //...




 @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       //...
        //initialize sensor list
        this.sensors = new ArrayList<Sensor>();

        //...
    }



    //method for adding new sensor
    public void addParams(){


        try{


        //add new sensor element to the list 
        this.sensors.add(new Sensor(this.param_name,Double.parseDouble(this.min_val),Double.parseDouble(this.max_val), 
                this.unit, this.selectedChartType, this.selectedFieldType, id_counter++));





        }catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("stack "+e.getStackTrace());
        }

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Successful", "New sensor added!")); 
    }

    //...

}
```

**UPDATE 3**: fix some namespace errors.

Comment: @BalusC : just for my curiosity, why did you make changes deleting some elements from my thread?

Comment: @Tiny: ok I get it, sorry for my question

Comment: Because they don't contribute to the actual problem. You'd in real still have exactly the same problem after removing them. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for other hints how to ask the right question.

Comment: @BalusC: ok thank you BalusC

Comment: four letters: mcve (see [ask])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my issue changing the implementation philosophy: I divide the tab contents in 2 separate xhtml files with related beans, the first one for "parent" element management and the second one for its child elements.

so, the first xhtml:

```
 <h:form> 
     <p:panel id="panel" header="New Station" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
          <p:inputText id="stationName" required="true" value="#{adminBean.stationName}"/>
          <p:inputText id="description" required="true" value="#{adminBean.description}" />

          <p:outputLabel value="Station type" for="stationType" />
              <p:selectOneMenu id="stationType" value="#{adminBean.selectedStationType}" >
                  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Type" itemValue="-1" noSelectionOption="false" />
                  <f:selectItems value="#{adminBean.stationType}" />
             </p:selectOneMenu>
         </h:panelGrid>
     </p:panel>


    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{adminBean.cancella}" icon="ui-icon-check"  />

    <p:commandButton value="Next >" id="nextId" binding="#{nextId}"  action="#{adminBean.nextStep}" 
                    icon="ui-icon-check" update=":growl" />
 </h:form>
```

when user selects the Next Button, a new page will be called and its bean will use the bean related with first page in order to retrieve all needed info and show its metadata correctly.

this is the second page:

```
<h:form> 
   <p:panel id="panel2" header="Aggiungi sensori" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
      <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">


          <p:inputText id="param_name" required="true" value="#{adminSensorsBean.param_name}"/>


          <p:selectOneMenu id="chartType" value="#{adminSensorsBean.selectedChartType}" >
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Type" itemValue="-1" noSelectionOption="false" />
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Line" itemValue="LINE" noSelectionOption="false" />
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bar" itemValue="BAR" noSelectionOption="false" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                //...

                <p:selectOneMenu id="fieldType" binding="#{fieldType}" value="#{adminSensorsBean.selectedFieldType}" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Field" itemValue="-1" noSelectionOption="false" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{adminSensorsBean.fieldsType}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

            </h:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>
            <p:commandButton value="Add Sensor" id="addSensorId" binding="#{addSensorId}" 
                             action="#{adminSensorsBean.addSensor}" 
                             icon="ui-icon-check" update=":growl :#{tblSensors.clientId}" />
        </h:form>

        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable id="tblSensors"  
                var="sensorElem" 
                value="#{adminSensorsBean.sensors}"
                scrollable="true"
                rowKey="#{sensorElem.id}"
                binding="#{tblSensors}"
                scrollHeight="150"
            >  
               //...
               //this table will be filled with data from form above
               //...

            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>


        //...
        <h:form> 
           <p:commandButton value="Submit" id="submitId" binding="#{submitId}" action="#{adminSensorsBean.saveStation}" 
                    icon="ui-icon-check" update=":growl" />
        </h:form>
```

through the Add Sensor button new information will be inserted into the tableView by the called bean method.

```
@ManagedBean(name="adminSensorsBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AdminSensorsBean implements Serializable{

//Managed property from bean of first page
@ManagedProperty(value="#{adminBean}")
    private AdminBean adminBean;

 //...

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    //Here all second page elements as FieldType list, will be initialized using stored information from managed property.

}

//...
```

}

In this way everything works fine! Honestly I don't known why update event didn't work when I putted all my code in only one jsf page..is it a PrimeFaces/JSF bug? maybe but I don't sure.
Thank you for the support, and sorry for my rough english

Answer (score 0):

althouh I'm not familiar with dataTables with data bindings, I think the update-statement is not correct, you need to update the datatable when triggering the commandButton

```
update=":growl, :tblSensors"
```

Comment: I have to use data bindings because the component that I want to update is defining after commandButton declaration. In fact if I try your suggestion I'll get the handlerRenderException with "Cannot find component for expression :tblSensors".

Comment: Update the `<h:form>` arround your datatable to look like `<h:form prependId="false">` and retry Raphael Roth suggestion.

Comment: @MathieuCastets: why `prependId="false"`? I try to not use it due to 'issues' like that prepending is still needed in Ajax calls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/jsf-namingcontainer-and-uiform-with-prependid

Comment: Interesting link indeed, thank you! That was just a short comment in order to merely test if update would work with the right component id. Then I would have redirected OP to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438707/how-to-update-primefaces-component-in-one-page-from-command-button-in-another-pa

Comment: @MathieuCastets  : thank you for your support! I always use data binding approach when I use PrimeFaces and JSF and It always works fine! I think the problem isn't the use of prependId... I'm not able to see the problem... :S

Comment: @MathieuCastets I tried to rewrite the xhtml structure in order to not use data binding method. But the problem still remain. Moreover I saw that when bean method is called and some variable has been changed; this changes aren't persistent and they are missed every time the method is called

Comment: What's your bean's scope?

Comment: @MathieuCastets : session scope

Answer (score 0):

Why not just specify the form id so that updating child elements will be more straightforward? try:

```
<h:form> 
        ...
        <p:commandButton value="Add parameters" action="#{amminBean.addParams}"  
                         update=":growl :datatableform:tblSensors"  />
</h:form>

<h:form id="datatableform">
    <p:dataTable id="tblSensors"  
            var="sensorElem" value="#{aminBean.sensors}"
            binding="#{tblSensors}">  
            ...
        </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: unfortunately your suggestion doesn't resolve my problem (yesterday I tried your solution but problem still remain). I think the problem is on bean method. In debug mode I saw that every changes performed on server side attributes aren't persistent and this sound strange (I'm using Session Scoped). When I call the bean method through the commandButton, I saw that it seams to run fine but at the end of the method all data changes are lost.. and consequently there are no new data for tblSensors datatable

Comment: can you post related snippets of your backing bean?

Comment: hi, is '#{amminBean.addParams}' and '#{aminBean.sensors}' just typos? they're supposed to be using 'adminBean' right? also, your p:commandButton is calling addParams method but what you posted in your backing bean is named addSensor().

Comment: yes I'm sorry, I forget to change the object names.

Comment: moreover adminBean.sensors is linked to the ArrayList containing the information I want to show in the tableView and adminBean.addParams is linked to the bean method that create and append new element in the ArrayList